# isolate conditionalPanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've got a `shiny` tab where the user can select several parameters via `selectInput`. After the selection, the user clicks on an `actionButton` and a bunch of calculations happen on the server side. Depending on both the results and the selections, one or several `conditionalPanels` are supposed to be shown. The problem is that once the user changes the selection, the displayed `conditionalPanel` changes immediately. However, I'd like the conditions only to be evaluated after the user has pushed the `actionButton` again and the calculations on the server side have been updated. Is there a way to tie the condition of the `conditionalPanel` on an `actionButton`?

Here is the best MWE I could come up with to capture all the nuances (actually, the dependency of the conditional panels on some server results is still missing here):

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
              c("SLength" = "Sepal.Length",
                "SWidth" = "Sepal.Width",
                "PLength" = "Petal.Length",
                "PWidth" = "Petal.Width",
                "Species" = "Species"),
              multiple = TRUE),
  br(),
  actionButton("goButton", "Go!"), 
  hr(),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input['variable'].length == 1",
                   plotOutput("oneplot")),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input['variable'].length == 2",
                   plotOutput("twoplot"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  v <- reactiveValues(plot.type = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$goButton, {
    if (is.null(input$variable)) return(NULL)
    if ("Species" %in% input$variable & length(input$variable > 1)){
      sec.var <- input$variable[which(input$variable != "Species")]
      v$summary <- ldply(by(iris[,sec.var], iris$Species, mean))
      v$summary[,1] <- as.factor(v$summary[,1])
    } else if ("Species" %in% input$variable)
      v$summary <- table(iris$Species) else
        v$summary <- iris[,input$variable]
  })

  output$oneplot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(v$summary)) return(NULL)
    if (input$variable == "Species") return(NULL)
    hist(v$summary)
  })

  output$twoplot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(v$summary)) return(NULL)
    plot(v$summary)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So let's say I start the app and select `SLength` and `SWidth`, click the `Go`-Button and get a dotplot. Then I'd want to show `SLength` vs. `PLength`, so I delete `SWidth`from the selection field and the same moment I get two histograms, one for each of the previous selections. The conditional panel immediately reacts to the change of `input$variable`, while the observer within the server script is still waiting for me to push the button. Obviously, that's not the behaviour the user would expect. The expected behaviour would be that the evaluation of the conditions of the conditional panels only happens upon pushing the `Go`-button. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing condition on server side?

```
    library(shiny)
    library(plyr)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                  c("SLength" = "Sepal.Length",
                    "SWidth" = "Sepal.Width",
                    "PLength" = "Petal.Length",
                    "PWidth" = "Petal.Width",
                    "Species" = "Species"),
                  multiple = TRUE),
      br(),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!"), 
      hr(),
       plotOutput("oneplot")
     # conditionalPanel(condition = "input['variable'].length == 1",
     #                  plotOutput("oneplot")),
     # conditionalPanel(condition = "input['variable'].length == 2",
      #                 plotOutput("twoplot"))
    )

    server <- function(input, output){
      v <- reactiveValues(plot.type = NULL)

      observeEvent(input$goButton, {
        if (is.null(input$variable)) return(NULL)
        if ("Species" %in% input$variable & length(input$variable > 1)){
          sec.var <- input$variable[which(input$variable != "Species")]
          v$summary <- ldply(by(iris[,sec.var], iris$Species, mean))
          v$summary[,1] <- as.factor(v$summary[,1])
        } else if ("Species" %in% input$variable)
          v$summary <- table(iris$Species) else
            v$summary <- iris[,input$variable]
      })

      output$oneplot <- renderPlot({
        #Added actionButton dependency here
        input$goButton
        isolate({
        if(length(input$variable)== 1) {
            if (is.null(v$summary)) return(NULL)
            if (input$variable == "Species") return(NULL)
            hist(v$summary)
        }
        else {
             if (is.null(v$summary)) return(NULL)
            plot(v$summary)
        }
        })
      })

      #output$twoplot <- renderPlot({

        #if (is.null(v$summary)) return(NULL)
        #plot(v$summary)

      #})
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

EDIT: Added another option by using submitButton

You can also use `submitButton()` and attach `observeEvent()` to `input$variable()`.     "Forms that include a submit button do not automatically update their outputs when inputs change, rather they wait until the user explicitly clicks the submit button." [submitButton](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/submitButton.html)

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
              c("SLength" = "Sepal.Length",
                "SWidth" = "Sepal.Width",
                "PLength" = "Petal.Length",
                "PWidth" = "Petal.Width",
                "Species" = "Species"),
              multiple = TRUE),
  br(),
  submitButton("Go!"), 
  hr(),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input['variable'].length == 1",
                   plotOutput("oneplot")),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input['variable'].length == 2",
                   plotOutput("twoplot"))
)

server <- function(input, output){
  v <- reactiveValues(plot.type = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$variable, {
    if (is.null(input$variable)) return(NULL)
    if ("Species" %in% input$variable & length(input$variable > 1)){
      sec.var <- input$variable[which(input$variable != "Species")]
      v$summary <- ldply(by(iris[,sec.var], iris$Species, mean))
      v$summary[,1] <- as.factor(v$summary[,1])
    } else if ("Species" %in% input$variable)
      v$summary <- table(iris$Species) else
        v$summary <- iris[,input$variable]
  })

  output$oneplot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(v$summary)) return(NULL)
    if (input$variable == "Species") return(NULL)
    hist(v$summary)
  })

  output$twoplot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(v$summary)) return(NULL)
    plot(v$summary)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That works fine if you only have different plots dependent on the input. However, I might have either a plot, or a table, or a text, or a plot and a text together (I didn't want to make the example too complicated, so I skipped that part). If I use `renderPlot` with a condition and `renderText` with another condition, and upon this particular combination of conditions only the text should be printed, the ui still reserves space for the plot (so there is a white rectangle which would be occupied by a plot otherwise). So I don't think I can achieve the desired result with server side conditions.